# minimum effective schedule interval ( iphone objective c )

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.2, iphone-sdk-3.1.3

I think there is a `minimum time span` that we can assign as `interval` to schedule a task in iPhone SDK.
But I haven't found that `minimum interval/time span` yet.

Would you let me know please! It will be very helpful to me.

**EDIT**

Any detail reference is more appreciative.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

NSTimeInterval is just a "double", so can specify any double value.  The smallest value next to 0 is about 2.225e-308.

However, remember that NSTimer is not a high-precision tool.  You can specify very small intervals,  but they aren't honored by the OS. Here's what the [documentation for NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) says:

> the effective resolution of the time interval for a timer is limited to on the order of 50-100 milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

0.0 I believe. I've seen this used as a "trick" to get the system to run something immediately after the current thread goes into a wait state.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:

*"The minimum time before which the message is sent. Specifying a delay of 0 does not necessarily cause the selector to be performed immediately. The selector is still queued on the thread’s run loop and performed as soon as possible."*

The implication is, you can specify 0.

Comment: frankly speaking- `0` interval is useless, since i can do it without scheduler. Is it means that i can specify something like 0.000000000001, which is greater than `0`?

Comment: I wouldn't say 0 interval is useless. It's actually quite useful if you want something to run immediately after your thread enters sleep... for example, I use it in my ApplicationDidFinishLaunching method because I need the rest of the application initialization to finish (for example, to handle a url request), but still want to run the method the instant the thread is ready. Yes, you can specify any valid double precision floating point value >= 0.

Comment: Why not use one of the `performSelector` variants in that case?

Comment: That's what I referenced. Not sure I understand the comment.